# Why we don't have a high fantasy tag?

Tags: feature-request, specific-tag

We have tags for different fantasy genres: [low-fantasy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-fantasy), [urban-fantasy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urban-fantasy), and well as [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) for general fantasy questions, but what always struck me as odd is that we don't have a tag for high fantasy. Why so?

Comment: I wouldn't say that "magic" and "fantasy" are synonymous. There are plenty fantastic stories which do not involve explicit magic. There are even fantastic stories which explicitly declare that magic doesn't exist...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags are created on the fly, they're not preplanned under any sort of structure. Some people have used [low-fantasy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-fantasy) and [urban-fantasy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urban-fantasy) but not all that many in the grand scheme of things. If anyone with over 300 rep had wanted to use [high-fantasy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-fantasy) then it would exist.

Comment: But, honestly, Tolkien is sort of our collective default.